# How to insert echo into div

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm new here, so do not be angry if I ask something that is already answered.

I connected sql database:
connect.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mobilni", $connect) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

displaydata.php

```
<?php  
include "connection.php";
$sql= "SELECT * FROM imena WHERE Okrug='Beogradski'";
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

?>
<div class="beyondheader"></div>
<div class="header">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Početna</a></li>
            <li><a href='proizvodjaci.html'>Proizvodjači</a></li>
            <li><a href='oglasi.html'>Oglasi</a></li>
            <li><a href='about.html'>O nama</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="middle">
    <div class="leftmiddle">ss
    </div>
    <div class="rightmiddle">
        <?php 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        ?>
        <div class="divmobilni">
            Ime:<div class="mobilniime"><?php echo $row['Ime'];?></div>

            Okrug:<?php echo $row['Okrug'];?>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And everything is working fine. Now I want to put every result in the other `<div>` automatically?
How to do that?

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I want to sort results to be like this, in one `<div>` goes: `Ime:` `Okrug:` [that is data for one person]
Now, I want to make that all data from my SQL table display on this page, but every Person separately from this `<div>`.
To be something like this, with data from table: (This is just [example drawn in Paint](http://postimg.org/image/4zsia4djz/))
[image: example drawn in Paint]

I fixed this with adding only break to the end of PHP. Thanks in any case!

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, please try to rephrase and explain more.

Comment: what's the "other" div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same as you would with php open and close `<?php` `?>`

Use this inside the divs you would like or just use echo with the div inside